# Alert box after a value is entered and compared against a database populated value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, database

Hey there StackOverFlow!

**Explaining the code (HTML)**

```
<input tabIndex="0" title="Please enter transaction amount." id="TR_Amount" style="width: 425px;" maxLength="10" value=""/>
<input name="TR_Amount" type="hidden" value=""/>

<BR />

<input tabIndex="0" title="" class="InfoColor" id="check_amt" style="width: 141px;" maxLength="30" readOnly="" value=""/>
<input name="check_amt" type="hidden" value=""/>

<BR />
<DIV>
<LABEL title="" class=DefaultBold>Reserve Amount: 
<LABEL tabIndex=-1 title="" class=AttentionColor>#SAvlAmt#</LABEL>
</LABEL>
</DIV>
```

The HTML has two text boxes, one which is editable and one which is readonly, with two hidden boxes that grab the value without the boxes without the $ signs.

Upon entering a number in the first (TR_Amount) text box, the second one automatically copies that amount on blur/change.

It also has a label, which has a value that is automatically replaced upon loading of the page. (*So #SAvlAmt# becomes the amount that the database holds for that variable for our system*) This value has two different values. One with the $ sign and one without that is just running when the page is submitted.

**JavaScript**

```
function amtGreatRes(){
    var ChkAmount = $('input[name="check_amt"]').val(); // Works
    var ReserveAmt = $('#AvlAmt').val(); // My confusion
    if(ChkAmount > ReserveAmt){
        jAlert('The payment amount entered exceeds the reserve amount for this transaction. Please correct payment amount.');
    }else{jAlert('You did it!');}
}
```

**QUESTION**

Now the problem/question is: How would I first **grab the database populated value**?

Then, using that amount, do a **comparison to the entered amount in the readonly field** which is generated from the data entered into the TR_Amount input box?

**JSFiddle**
[JSFiddle of Current Work - In - Progress](http://jsfiddle.net/ds9fx/30/)

*The code for auto updating the readonly field is already in place. So the main thing is figuring out how to grab that database value without it's $ sign so that when the user clicks out of the box for their payment, they will be greeted with an alert box telling them that they entered way more than is allocated for this transaction*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To grab the value from the label try this -

```
<LABEL tabIndex=-1 title="" class=AttentionColor id="myLbl">#SAvlAmt#</LABEL>

var ReserveAmt = parseFloat($('#myLbl').text().replace('$', ''));
```

//update the reason your comparison isn't working is because you need to convert the values to float -
Like this -

```
var ChkAmount = parseFloat($('input[name="check_amt"]').val());
var ReserveAmt = parseFloat($('#lblAmt').text().replace('$', ''));
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rossmartin/VEetU/)

Comment: I was considering adding an ID, I would then need to remove the $ from the amount that shows there. Which I assume are regex global flags?

Comment: You could do `var ReserveAmt = $('#myLbl').text().replace('$', '');`

Comment: @Doodely I updated my answer and added a fiddle.  Still fiddling.

Comment: Now making the IF statement run that says if that amount that we put into TR_Amount is > the labels number [which now has no $ sign, thank you kindly!] then an alert should trigger.

Comment: @Doodely Ok I believe my jsFiddle now does everything that you want - http://jsfiddle.net/rossmartin/VEetU/

Comment: UGH! Forgot about parse T-T Sighhh, too many signs everywhere with database'n and JQuery.

Thank you ROSS! This should definitely lead me to the right way now with my system :)